# Office 2007 - Referencing sources in Word

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office-2007

I can reference it,

put in reference #1... to reference #10

and then cross reference reference #10 to reference #5

then you add a new reference #4

and the cross reference doesnt update.

How can you get the cross references to update automatically?

Comment: What kind of references are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft Word inserts cross-references as fields. If an item you referred to in a cross-reference isn't correct, you need to manually update the cross-reference fields by selecting a specific cross-reference or the entire document and then pressing F9. Another option is to reference bookmarks.

Here are some resources you could check:

- [Troubleshoot cross-references](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word/HP051893681033.aspx)
- [Inserting Cross References in Word 2007](http://wordprocessing.about.com/od/microsoftword2007/a/crossreferences.htm)
- [Change a cross-reference](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word/HP051893621033.aspx)